# How can I output audio to both of my monitors simultaneously in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors both plugged in via DisplayPort. Both monitors also have HDMI inputs, but I am only using the DisplayPort inputs. They are plugged into the same discrete graphics card.

My computer has an ASUS motherboard with a good sound card built-in.

I never liked that I can only choose one or the other monitor to output sound to. I would like sound to be output from both monitors at the same time, though I do not want a delay between the two.

How can I output sound to both monitors at the same time in Windows 7?

Comment: What are you using to select which (monitor speaker) to output sound to exactly?

Comment: I'm using windows audio devices.

Answer (score 5):

Windows apparently does not support this, but your sound card might.

Since, I have an asus mb I suspect that you have a realtek hd audio sound card, if not I suspect the process is similar. First, you have to get the audio driver from the realtek site if you don't already have, because the windows divers won't support it. Then you have to go to your audio devices and show disabled devices and enable "stereo mix". Go into properties and go to the listen tab and select listen to device which will "listen" for the sound in your main device. Underneath that button their is a menu "playback through this device" and select the second device i.e. your second monitor.

A more low tech solution might just be to buy a audio jack splitter and plug audio jacks from the splitter into both screens.

hope this helps!

Comment: This appears to be a failed attempt to advertise/promote a YouTube video.  If I am mistaken, then I apologize but answers here at Superuser, should stand by themselves.  Currently without the video your answer does not answer the author's question, even if you had fully explained the what was described in the video, it would not be appropriate to promote the YouTube video honestly.

Comment: @Ramhound It was not an attempt to promote a video. I'm not the author nor do I know the author. I'm sorry if it appeared that way. It seemed like away to solve his problem but I wanted to give credit to my source, which I forgot to include the link anyway. But I will edit that out if that is not appropriate.

Comment: +2 for buy an audio jack splitter. May be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [Audio-Router](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router)'s "Duplicate" function:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you edit this answer to explain why Audio-Router is a good solution, and provide some examples of its usage?

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Confirmed to work with 2 monitors connected via HDMI to the same NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: After seeing this solution here and elsewhere, I installed Audio-Router. Route output from an application to left monitor. Duplicate the app, see screenshot. Change routing of the duplicate to right monitor. The result is one application with output to two monitor devices. This might not be the best solution, but this is a valid Answer to this question and should get Accepted. In my audio settings I set left monitor to output only Left audio and right for Right. My laptop has a Thunderbolt 3 USB-C jack and I have an adapter from USB-C to 2 HDMI cables. No special software. Works instantly.

Comment: Had high hopes but I get an error that audio routing is not available. Also, print screen is disabled while the application is running. I hope I didn't make a mistake allowing that software to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/) and [VB-audio virtual cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/).
Open up voicemeeter and set your hardware out to both monitors, then set your virtual input to VB-Audio. After that set your default playback device to VB-Audio

It should look like this

[image: It should look like this]

I was looking for something like this and come across the solution accidentally.