# How do I route audio from a multi-channel (e.g. 5.1) sound to multiple speakers using VoiceMeeter?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, speakers, voicemeeter

Similar to [How can I output audio to both of my monitors simultaneously in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/1169370/how-can-i-output-audio-to-both-of-my-monitors-simultaneously-in-windows-7) but I want to do something specific with my two monitors both having audio output.

In Windows I can configure VoiceMeeter to be 5.1 but only use 3 audio channels L, C and R.  What I'd like to do is set it up so the left monitor left speaker is mapped to L the right monitor right speaker is mapped to R and the remaining two are mapped and duplicated to C
[image]

The test audio does show muliple channels are going through but after the L R channel it's quiet.  My guess is I may have to do something with composite but I am not really sure what exactly.  I also tried Banana but couldn't figure out what to do there either.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Voicemeeter Standard is not proposing independent physical bus, so
you may use Voicemeeter Banana or Potato and see use case number 6 on this page: https://voicemeeter.com/mix-down-and-mix-up-the-voicemeeter-bus-modes/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also as per my OP, I have noted that I am already trying to use Voicemeeter Banana